# Network error in storm, how to debug?

Tags: apache-storm

I setup a storm cluster on 10 VMs and verified on the storm UI page that all the 10 supervisors are shown there.

But when I submit a jar file, using `bin/storm jar my.jar my.class --remote`, I see the following error on all the supervisor nodes and all the supervisor nodes die.

```
2016-03-24 22:06:52.703 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server 10.10.10.147/10.10.10.147:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-03-24 22:06:52.704 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Socket connection established to 10.10.10.147/10.10.10.147:2181, initiating session
2016-03-24 22:06:52.709 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Session establishment complete on server 10.10.10.147/10.10.10.147:2181, sessionid = 0x253355aaaaa001a, negotiated timeout = 20000
2016-03-24 22:06:52.712 o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [INFO] State change: CONNECTED
2016-03-24 22:06:52.765 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] Starting supervisor with id 27e6171a-2e94-491f-b961-777067660304 at host storm-supervisor-1-11026402-1-109466741.example.company.com
2016-03-24 22:08:10.286 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] Downloading code for storm id kafka-elastic-topology-2-1458856253 from /var/storm/storm-local/nimbus/stormdist/kafka-elastic-topology-2-1458856253
2016-03-24 22:08:10.297 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [2000] the maxSleepTimeMs [60000] the maxRetries [5]
2016-03-24 22:08:20.361 b.s.event [ERROR] Error when processing event
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.retryNext(TBackoffConnect.java:59) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:51) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:103) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.<init>(ThriftClient.java:72) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.<init>(NimbusClient.java:74) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:37) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.downloadFromMaster(Utils.java:361) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__7720.invoke(supervisor.clj:581) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:241) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$mk_synchronize_supervisor$this__7638.invoke(supervisor.clj:465) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__7258.invoke(event.clj:40) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_51]
Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:103) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:48) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:103) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:48) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    ... 11 more
2016-03-24 22:08:20.376 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Error when processing an event")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error when processing an event")
    at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:336) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__7258.invoke(event.clj:48) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_51]
2016-03-24 22:08:20.381 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] Shutting down supervisor 27e6171a-2e94-491f-b961-777067660304
```

The same topology and the jar file was working when I was running on 10 equivalent non-VMs

So it seems that the error is related to networking between the VMs.

Does anyone know how I can debug this?

Please note that I have changed the IP addresses 10.10.10... manually in the logs to avoid posting real ones here.

Answer (score 0):

All ports on the non-VMs (i.e. the physical machines) were open and hence they could talk to each other. This was not so on the VMs.

Things worked fine when I opened the relevant ports 6700 to 6705, 8000 and 8080.

But the error message is really misleading. It should have been more explicit with the host-name and the port its using.

Comment: you mean open ports of the remote machine?